# Upgraded to Apache/2.4.29... all my htaccess rewriting rules not working anymore ...why?

Tags: 14.04, apache2

Just upgraded to Apache/2.4.29... all my .htaccess rewriting rules not working anymore. What to do now?

Comment: First check if mod_rewrite is installed with phpinfo.

Comment: Do you get any substantial messages in error.log? Except for the odd change in single directives the main changes from Apache 2.2 to 2.4 is in the authorization and access control (cmp.: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html)